# Why does IoAllocateErrorLogEntry return null?

Tags: wdm

I am trying to write my first Windows 2000 driver and like to use the EventViewer for debugging.

So I wrote something like this:

```
DriverEntry(DriverObject, SomeRegistryPathIDontCareAbout){
    ntoskrnl.exe/IoAllocateErrorLogEntry(
        IoObject = DriverObject,
        EntrySize = 44
    )

    return 0;
}
```

ntoskrnl.exe/IoAllocateErrorLogEntry just returns 0 instead of an address. Does someone know why the function refuses to allocate some space for an event package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

`IoAllocateErrorLogEntry` checks if the value of `EntrySize` is >= `sizeof(IO_ERROR_LOG_PACKET)` which is 48 bytes.

So my value of 44 bytes was simply too low.